# Insert multiple rows in Jooq throws compilation error

Tags: java, jooq

I have a table called `VARS` that has two columns `VAR_NAME` and `VAR_TYPE`. I also have a list of POJOs to insert in this table. The POJO class is called `Var` and has two fields called `varName` and `varType`.

**Note** that the fields match so `Jooq` can derive and apply in the insert.

When I try to insert the list of Vars, I get a compilation error:

```
    InsertSetStep<VarsRecord> insert = create.insertInto(VARS);

    for (Var var: vars) {
        VarsRecord rec = new VarsRecord();
        rec.from(var);
        insert.set(rec);
    }

    insert.execute();   // <-- error here
```

The error:

> The method execute() is undefined for the type
>   InsertSetStep

- How to run this insert?
- What should be used instead of `InsertSetStep<VarsRecord>`?
- Should I excecute an `insertInto` for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid the historic mutability of the DSL API [as it might change in the next major release](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl/). Use [`DSLContext.batchInsert(Collection<? extends TableRecord>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchInsert-java.util.Collection-) instead:

```
List<VarsRecord> list = new ArrayList<>(vars.size());
for (Var var : vars) {
    VarsRecord rec = new VarsRecord();
    rec.from(var);
    list.add(rec);
}
create.batchInsert(list).execute();
```

Comment: For some reason the `batchInsert` is not inserting any rows, even though the `list` contains records. I'm running this code in a Stateless EJB with CMT, why could this happen?

Comment: @ps0604: Yeah, I'm stupid. I forgot the `execute()` call